# Как в XML найти узел по атрибуту и удалить или изменить?

Tags: c#, xml

1. Как найти узел по атрибуту?
2. Как найти узел по атрибуту и удалить?
3. Как найти узел по атрибуту и изменить атрибут?

Только без *LINQ*.

Пример XML-файла.

```
System.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<users>
  <user name="Bill Gates">
    <company>Microsoft</company>
    <age>48</age>
  </user>
  <user name="Larry Page">
    <company>Google</company>
    <age>48</age>
  </user>
</users>
```

Comment: Какие технологии разрешено использовать? Есть ли схема XML?

Comment: А откуда взялось странное требование не пользоваться LINQ?

Comment: Хочу сначала разобраться без linq потом с linq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.

```
XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//element[@name='value']");
```

2.

```
for (int i = nodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{ 
    nodes[i].ParentNode.RemoveChild(nodes[i]);
}
```

3.

```
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//element[@name='value']");
node.Attributes[0].Value = newValue;
```